# Something wrong with my grid

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm building the game of life and my grid doesn't display correctly.

If you resize the browser (shrinking it), the grid of cells looks very out of proportion.

It must be something wrong with the way I set the grid and square sizes.

I'm relatively beginner in CSS, so any help is greatly appreciated! Below is my attempt:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Grid} from './Grid';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.rows = 30;
    this.cols= 50;
    this.state = {generation:0, gridFull: Array(this.rows).fill(Array(this.cols).fill(0)) };
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.state.gridFull)
  return (

      <div className="App">
     <Grid gridFull = {this.state.gridFull} rows={this.rows} cols= {this.cols}/>

       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Cell} from './Cell';
import './App.css'; 


export class Grid extends Component{

    render(){

    return(
        <div className="grid" style={{border: '2px solid black'}}>
       {this.props.gridFull.map((boardrow,i) => 
          (<div key={i} className="board-row">
            {boardrow.map((square,k) => 

                <Cell key={k}/>
            )}
          </div>)
       )}

       </div>
        )
    }
}

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

export class Cell extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="square" style={{ width: '1.67em', height: '1.67em' }}>
            </div>
            )
    }
}

.App {
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

}

.board-row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}


.square {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black ;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}
.square:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you create a demo?

Comment: Sorry! Here's the result: http://game-of-life-test-cmtran7393.c9users.io:8080/